# How to delay retry of failed attempt to execute Spark task

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

With `spark.task.maxFailures` set to a value > 1, Spark will automatically retry a failed task up to the number of allowed failures.

If the failure is due to an intermittent failure (for example a blob storage account is temporarily unavailable), retrying with exponential back-off would be preferable to an immediate rescheduling of the task onto the executor (which seems to be the default behavior).

How can I make Spark delay subsequent attempts at executing the task?

Comment: Do you mean, that you want to re-try a spark-submit after a delay? If so, you must configure this delay in schedulers (like airflow or oozie). I dont think spark itself can handle this internally

Comment: So Spark internally has a mechanism where it can retry a failed task – for example, the task could fail if a machine goes down. That's why the RDDs are "resilient". But I want to delay that retry (for example, by one minute). The reason is that my data source sometimes has problems; one such problem is that one or more files are being replaced and there is a small timespan where reading the file will result in a 404 Not Found.